# AWS & Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a local image based on CentOS with a specific application running on it. Running the application locally on my machine works fine. I want to take this image and upload it to AWS (preferably to an ElasticBeanstalk instance but I can work with other types).

**I cannot upload the image to a image repository like docker hub or other type** The application is by a third party and they gave us special permission to make the image and run it on AWS but we can not place the image in a repository.

Is there a way to just export my docker image (I have the saved TAR file) and upload it to AWS and have them use it directly? I've searched and searched and not found anything showing how to do that, all I have found indicate you have to have it in a repository or upload the code to AWS and have it build the image.

Thank you

Comment: `docker save` and `docker load`; you also might ask your third party whether you can upload to a private AWS ECR repository.

Comment: Yeah - I'd just clarify with them on what they meant by repository - Running a private ECR repository, or even just your own Docker Registry (Docker has docs on how to do this) seems like that should be fine. Would make things world's easier